# Is there any cross-platform tool for AvaloniaUI to log events?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, avaloniaui, avalonia

What logger should i use at AvaloniaUI? I know about Serilog, but is it cross-platform? Is there any built-in tool for this?

Moreover i need to log info to the .log file. This must be cross-platform (Windows, Linux and MacOS).

Comment: check the documentation please https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/getting-started/logging-errors-and-warnings simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Avalonia can log warnings and errors using `System.Diagnostics.Trace`.
> To enable logging the `LogToTrace` method call should be present in
> your `Program.cs` file:

```
public static AppBuilder BuildAvaloniaApp()
    => AppBuilder.Configure<App>()
        .UsePlatformDetect()
        .LogToTrace();
```

And yes, you can log to file.

> By default these trace messages would be logger to your IDE output
> window. If you want to re-route these messages to different location,
> use API provided by System.Diagnostics.Trace.

See more info about this at [official site.](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/getting-started/logging-errors-and-warnings)